# How to assign variable in pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, immutability

I have a method that takes a year (int) as a parameter. Depending on the passed in year, I need to assign a variable and then use that variable in a query:

```
def findByYear (year: Int): Future[Int] = {
  val tableName = ""
  year match {
    case 1970 => tableName = "table1970" //this errors out
    case 1980 => tableName = "table1980" //this errors out
  }
  config.db.run {
    sqlu"SELECT count(*) from #${tableName}"
  }
}
```

The above errors out since scala doesn't allow re-assignment. Is there a better way to do this instead of putting the `config.db.run` clause inside each `case` which would become very repetitive code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pattern match expression evaluates to a value so it can be assigned to a `val` like any other expression, for example

```
    def findByYear (year: Int): Future[Int] = {
      val tableName = year match {
        case 1970 => "table1970"
        case 1980 => "table1980"
      }
      config.db.run {
        sqlu"SELECT count(*) from #${tableName}"
      }
    }
```

Even if-statements are actually expressions in Scala so we can assign them to `val`s:

```
val x = if (true) "on" else "off"
x // x: String = on
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to great answer from Mario, I would like to add additional case to pattern matching which handles incorrect input:

```scala
def findByYear (year: Int): Future[Option[Int]] = {
  val tableName: Option[String] = year match {
    case 1970 => Some("table1970")
    case 1980 => Some("table1980")
    case _    => None
  }
  tableName.map { name =>
    config.db.run {
      sqlu"SELECT count(*) from #${name}"
    }
  }.getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
}
```